# Using variables in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use variable inside `ng-repeat`, if it is defined outside  Angular.js directive?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
<script>
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
</script>

<div ng-repeat="n in items">
...
</div>

<script>
... do something with items ...
</script>
```

How to make a variable work both inside `ng-repeat` scope and outside it?

(Obviously I am not ninja in Angular :) )

Comment: You can add another ng-repeat directive, but notice that items is a global variable, so you can acess to it wherever you need in your page

Comment: What variable do you want to use `n` or `items`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods, either:

1. declare the `items` variable within a `scope` of `controller`. For e.g:

   ```
   myapp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
   }]);
   ```

   and then use this controller like this:

   ```
   <body ng-controller="testCtrl"> 
    <div ng-repeat="n in items">
     <!--your html here-->
    </div>
   </body>
   ```
2. or you can `init` it directly inside html like this:

   ```
   <body ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-init="items = ['a', 'b', 'c']"> 
    <div ng-repeat="n in items">
     <!--your html here-->
    </div>
   </body>
   ```

Comment: Which one is preferred?

Comment: I prefer the first method. Easy to find and modify the variable later. :)

Comment: @Pavlo the first one is preferred, see the [angular docs on ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit): its **only** recommended use is aliasing properties of nested ng-inits.

Comment: Yes, first method is what I needed. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 5):

If you define `items` like that, it is put on the global scope (in a browser environment, the window object).

The ng-repeat directive can only access variables on the scope of its controller. So you need to do something like this:

```
$scope.items = items;
```

while initializing your controller.